# Magento CE 1.9 rounding

Tags: tax, rounding

Is there any plan to introduce a rounding function in Magento that caters for rounding to either the nearest 10 cents or, even better, nearest 5 cents?
In Switzerland, all prices are inclusive of tax and rounded to the nearest 5 cents as this is the smallest coin in the Swiss currency.
12.72 becomes 12.70 and 12.73 becomes 12.75, etc.
I did find, and buy, a solution from an Italian company. It allows rounding to 1 digit but then 12.72 becomes 12.7 whereas I want to display 12.70.

Answer (score 1):

You can try "Magento 5-Rappen-Rundung for Swiss Magento Merchants" extension:
https://github.com/openstream/Magento5CentRounding

Answer (score 0):

There are some discussions regarding price rounding for Magento 2.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=rounding

It would be great for some type of customization to be allowed here, as it can really cause difficulties for brick and mortar stores to adjust their long-standing pricing model to Magento (think component pricing by the square inch) as well as many currencies that don't adopt a strict 2 decimal place rounding scheme.

This feature would be a good step towards Magento being Unbound. =)

I highly doubt there are going to be any new features for rounding in the 1.x series.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I successfully implement a simple workaround on magento 1.9.2:

Copy app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/store.php

to app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/store.php

Edit the new copied file on `function roundPrice($price){}`:

replace `return round ($ price, 2);`

with `return round($price * 2, 1)/2;`